# PHP JSON Array not returning all rows from my phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, json

I´m trying to select all the rows from db but it´s not returning me all the rows. What am I doing wrong below?

```html
$conn=mysql_connect('localhost:3307', 'root', 'usbw');
mysql_select_db('android',$conn);
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$conn);

$response=array();
$result=mysql_query("select * from news");


if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
     $temp=array();
     $temp["ID"]=$row["ID"];
     $temp["TitrNews"]=$row["TitrNews"];
     $temp["MiniMatnNews"]=$row["MiniMatnNews"];
     $temp["MatnNews"]=$row["MatnNews"];
     $temp["TArikh"]=$row["TArikh"];

 
 
    }

    $response["news"]=array();
    array_push($response["news"],$temp);

    $response["t"]=1;
 echo json_encode($response);
}
else {
    $response["t"]=0;
    $response["massage"]="peyda nashod";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Is there something wrong with this code? My output only displays the last row of my database

```html
{"news":[{"ID":"7","TitrNews":"hi","MiniMatnNews":"hello","MatnNews":":D","TArikh":"1395-09-08"}],"t":1}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must declare

```
$response["news"]=array();
```

outside (i.e. just before) of the while loop. In fact, you may also don't declare it, as `$response = array();` is enough to set our variable (and even dispensable ?).

Now, just before adding our $temp result, we reset the result container,so you only were seeing the last result !

AND :

```
 array_push($response["news"],$temp);
```

must be in the wile loop, as we want to add each individual  row to the final array.

Here is the way i would have choose :

```
$conn=mysql_connect('localhost:3307', 'root', 'usbw');
mysql_select_db('android',$conn);
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$conn);

$response=array();
$result=mysql_query("select * from news");

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $temp=array();
            $temp["ID"]=$row["ID"];
            $temp["TitrNews"]=$row["TitrNews"];
            $temp["MiniMatnNews"]=$row["MiniMatnNews"];
            $temp["MatnNews"]=$row["MatnNews"];
            $temp["TArikh"]=$row["TArikh"];
    // add a new element to the response["temp"] array, containing our result
            $response["news"][]=$temp;    
        }
        $response["t"]=1;
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else {
        $response["t"]=0;
        $response["massage"]="peyda nashod";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

Comment: tnx for your feedback

Comment: Updated with a piece of code, that may solve other issue

Comment: Found the second misplaced line : you did have 2 errors causing the same wrong behavior :)